# Why am I having so many records after a join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, view, left-join

I'm trying to join two tables; one reporting information on media campaigns and another on TV spots... Because the second table does not contain any information on campaigns, and because I don't really need it now, I'm joining the two tables based on the id of the TV spot (here, "creative_id") as well as date.

The problem is, there are approx. 6.7 million records in the first table, so I don't understand why, when I run this, I get more than 17 million... :( Can you help, please?

```
alter view halo2 as
select
h.date,h.channel,h.strategy,h.creative_id,h.programme,h.sub_programme,h.l_c_b,
h.media_plan_split,h.pu,h.conversion_type,h.conversion_new_or_upgrade,
case when h.conversion_new_or_upgrade like '%new%' then 1 else 0 end #acquisitions,
case when h.conversion_new_or_upgrade like '%upg%' then 1 else 0 end #upgrades,
case when h.conversion_contract_length like '%12%' then 12
when h.conversion_contract_length like '%24%' then 24
when h.conversion_contract_length like '%30%' then 1
else 0 end contract_length_in_months,
h.conversion_device_manufacturer,
h.conversion_device,
h.media_spend,
h.#halo,
ft.u10/100 as upfront_cost,
(ft.sales_value+cast(ft.u28 as float))/100 as monthly_cost
from halo h left join in_ft_conversion ft
on h.creative_id=ft.creative_id 
and
h.date=ft.sales_date
```

Comment: Because you have a one to many relationship. If you perform a `JOIN` to another table, which has multiple matches, you will receive 1 row for each match; not 1 row with all of them.

Comment: That's how `JOIN`s work, pretty much. They relate rows from one table to zero, one, or many rows from another table.

Comment: This is not clear. Please give a [mcve]. Explain what you think LEFT JOIN does justified by referencing documentaiton & how you think that's not what you get. PS Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join. PS Consider the PKs/UNIQUEs & FKs of your tables.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two tables:

```
TableA
Number, Text
----
1, Hello
1, There
1, World


TableB
Number, Text
----
1, Foo
1, Bar
1, Baz
```

Here is a query that joins them:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.Number = b.Number
```

Here are the results:

```
a.Number, a.Text, b.Number, b.Text
----------------------------------
1, Hello, 1, Foo
1, Hello, 1, Bar
1, Hello, 1, Baz
1, There, 1, Foo
1, There, 1, Bar
1, There, 1, Baz
1, World, 1, Foo
1, World, 1, Bar
1, World, 1, Baz
```

This is called a Cartesian product; there isn't a 1:1 or even a 1:Many mapping between A and B, there is a Many:Many mapping. Each row in A maps to each row in B, the result that we started out with 3 rows in A, 3 rows in B, if they'd been 1:1 we'd have a 3 row resultset, but because each of 3 rows match up to another 3 rows, we got a 9 row result (3 * 3).

Any time that one of your tables has rows that match to more than one row of another table, as according to your join condition, your resulting row count will increase/multiply

Answer (score 0):

The most common situation is you have more than one record in the joined table that satisfies the join condition(Predicate). If your predicate is not unique on the second table records will repeat on left join.

Comment: Well, there are two predicates in that join; its not necessarily solely creative_id that is the problem

Comment: You're right! There are more fields in the predicate.