# SQL/SAS many repeat records with JOIN

Tags: sql, join, sas

I have two tables, I would like to combine them so that each ISIN item with transaction date adds the appropriate value from the second table. However, as in the picture, it shows me the results where the same value is added to each item, I would like them to be non-repeatable. How to connect or fix this error.

DBMS : SAS
[image]

```
PROC SQL;
create table Instrumenty_2 as
select 
b.WBIL_BRUTTO_PLN
,b.WYCENA_UJE_PLN
,b.KOD_ISIN 
from bmd.PAP_WART_SPR_&thismonth as b
;
quit;
PROC SQL;
create table Instrumenty_4 as
select 
ISIN_CODE
,TRADE_DATE
,SETTLEMENT_DATE
,MATURITY_DATE
,QUANTITY
,GROSS_AMOUNT
from kondor.k_papiery as a
left join Instrumenty_2 as b
on b.KOD_ISIN = a.ISIN_CODE
where DATA_DANYCH EQ &gv_date.
and TYPE_OF_INSTR_SHORT_NAME = "OBLIGACJE" 
and CPTY_SHORT_NAME = "BAN1"


;
quit;
```

Comment: "Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL." (see: [SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql)) ==> **Please correct the tags!**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I having so many records after a join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55147656/why-am-i-having-so-many-records-after-a-join)

Comment: If the link from Luuk doesn't help, I suggest you start by querying the table `bmd.PAP_WART_SPR_&thismonth`  for the ISIN shown in your image.  If that returns more than one row ... bingo.  Since you use only the KOD_ISIN field in your second query, you might think about selecting distinct values of KOD_ISIN (remove the other two fields) when you create and populate the Instrumenty_2 table.

Comment: Please use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)
Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code & example input; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

At least one of your table has several entries of the variable you use to join. SAS acts then in the way you observe. What you could do is using distinct to prevent double rows, however I think this will not solve your problem. What you could do is try to join using additional columns or add some conditions on both tables. But without knowing the data, at least with some example, is offering help somewhat difficult.